# How to check installed app version on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, watch

I know how to check app version on iPhone and tried the same way for an app installed on Apple watch in Watch App General -> Usage however not able to see app version. Can anybody help me find the app version on apple watch?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to check an app's version for the app's tech support, so they told me to open the App Store on the watch, find the app and see if it says "Update" or "Open". The store shows the current version and if the button said "Open", it is up-to-date. I don't know yet how to check another way, but thought this may help you.

Comment: Please add tags to your question so people can find it !

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check the version on Apple Watch as per my investigation. mostly the apple watch version is the same as the iPhone app version.

Answer (score 0):

Swift way of getting the current app's version and build number.

add this `extension` to your project. either as a separate file or in one of your existing files.

then you can get the version and build number like this:

```
let version = Bundle.version // e.g: 1.2
let build = Build.build // e.g: 16
let versionAndBuild = Build.versionAndBuild // e.g: v1.2(16)
```

please be careful to not use `Build.version()` instead. it'll return `"0"`.

and here is the extension:

```
    import Foundation
    import WatchKit
    
    public extension Bundle {

    static var version: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
    }

    static var build: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as? String
    }

    static var versionAndBuild: String? {
        guard let version = Bundle.version,
              let build = Bundle.build else {
            return nil
        }
        return version == build ? "v\(version)" : "v\(version)(\(build))"
    }
    
}
```